# working with array of objects with conditions

Tags: javascript

Here we have an array of objects:

```
var slides = [
{ id: 1, performance: 20, guided_phrases: ["I was sent", "I don't know"] },
{ id: 2, performance: 30, guided_phrases: ["to earth"] },
{ id: 3, performance: 40, guided_phrases: ["to protect you"] },
{ id: 4, performance: 15, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] },
{ id: 5, performance: 50, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] }
];
```

I want to find the `id` of the slide which its `guided_phrases` **includes** a specific string (represented in `phrase variable` ) with the lowest `performance`...

So if we have `let phrase = "I was sent";` then the output should be slide id **4** because the performance is the lowest among slides 1 and 4 and 5.

I have tried this code but I need a hand to figure out a simple way to log the id:

```
let phrase = "I was sent";
let contain = [];
for(let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){

   if(slides[i].guided_phrases.includes(phrase)){

     contain.push(slides[i].performance)
     console.log(contain)
     let max = Math.min.apply(null, contain); 
     console.log(max)
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you just `sort` by performance, then using `find`?

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: close voter, please provide the reason...

Comment: You would not need to store the performances in the `contain` array. You should store only the last object (or its index) in a variable, then update that whenever you find a matching one with better performance than the last. Then log its id afterwards.

Comment: Are you going to search for `phrase` multiple times? If yes, you could create an object or a `Map` with each unique phrase as key and the `id` of the lowest `performance` as it's value. Now you could get the value with just `mappingObject[phrase]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with :

```
const slides = [
{ id: 1, performance: 20, guided_phrases: ["I was sent", "I don't know"] },
{ id: 2, performance: 30, guided_phrases: ["to earth"] },
{ id: 3, performance: 40, guided_phrases: ["to protect you"] },
{ id: 4, performance: 15, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] },
{ id: 5, performance: 50, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] }
];

const logID = (phrase) => {
  console.log(slides.filter(x => x.performance === Math.min(...slides.filter(slide => slide.guided_phrases.includes(phrase)).map(x => x.performance)))[0].id);
}

logID('I was sent');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution using some ES6:

```js
var slides = [
{ id: 1, performance: 20, guided_phrases: ["I was sent", "I don't know"] },
{ id: 2, performance: 30, guided_phrases: ["to earth"] },
{ id: 3, performance: 40, guided_phrases: ["to protect you"] },
{ id: 4, performance: 15, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] },
{ id: 5, performance: 50, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] }
];

let phrase = "I was sent";

const findLowestId = (arr) => slides.filter(x => {
   const reg = new RegExp(phrase)
   return x.guided_phrases.find(y=> y.match(reg)) 
}).sort((a,b)=> a.performance > b.performance)[0].id

console.log(findLowestId(slides))
```

Answer (score 2):

I used only one loop.

```js
var slides = [
{ id: 1, performance: 20, guided_phrases: ["I was sent", "I don't know"] },
{ id: 2, performance: 30, guided_phrases: ["to earth"] },
{ id: 3, performance: 40, guided_phrases: ["to protect you"] },
{ id: 4, performance: 15, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] },
{ id: 5, performance: 50, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] }
];

const search = 'I was sent';

let result = -1;
let performance = 0;
slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
  if(slide.guided_phrases.includes(search) > -1 && performance < slide.performance) {
    performance = slide.performance;
    result = index;
  }
});

console.log('Result:', result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it if you want a function that's readable and easy to follow:

```
const lowestPerformance = (slides, phrase) => {
    let currLowest = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        let slide = slides[i];

        if (slide.guided_phrases.includes(phrase)) {
            currLowest =  ((currLowest === null) || slide.performance < (currLowest.performance)) ? slide : currLowest;
        }
    }

    return currLowest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let phrase = "I was sent";
let contain = null;
let id = null;
for(let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){

   if(slides[i].guided_phrases.includes(phrase)){
     if (contain == null) {
       contain = slides[i].performance;
       id = slides[i].id;
     } else {
       if (contain > slides[i].performance) {
         contain = slides[i].performance;
         id = slides[i].id;
       }
     }
  }
}
console.log(id);
```